# How can a Firefox extension check whether Firefox is the active application?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I see the [activate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows#activate) and [deactivate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows#deactivate) events on `browserWindows`. They fire when Firefox becomes active or inactive, respectively, but they also fire when focus shifts from one Firefox window to another, and there seems to be no way to distinguish these two cases.

In particular, `browserWindows.activeWindow` is always the top Firefox window, regardless of whether Firefox is the active application.

I’d like to both 1) be able to check whether Firefox is the active application and 2) be notified when Firefox becomes active or inactive.

I’m willing to use XPCOM if necessary, but I can’t find what I’m looking for there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve just defined a global variable to track the state, relying on Firefox to always dispatch `deactivate` before `activate` when the user switches between Firefox windows:

```
var firefoxActive = true;  // assuming Firefox is active when addon starts

require('sdk/windows').browserWindows
.on('activate', function (win) {
  firefoxActive = true;
})
.on('deactivate', function (win) {
  firefoxActive = false;
});
```

I’d still appreciate any ideas on how to detect for sure whether Firefox is the active application initially.